# Web Service - Efficient way to transfer file to cloud platform storage

Tags: wcf, web-services, cloud, soa

I have a service that requires some input files from the client.  This service is run from a number of different cloud platforms (Amazon, Azure, etc.).  Further, it requires that these input files be stored in their respective cloud platform's persistent storage.  What is the best way to transfer those input files from the client to the service without requiring that the client knows about the specific cloud platform's details (e.g. secret keys)?

Given these requirements, the simple approach of the client transferring these files directly to the platform's storage (e.g. S3) isn't possible.

I could have the client call a service method and pass it the file blob to transfer up to the service, but that would require that the service receive the file, then do it's own file transfer to the cloud platform's storage (in other words, do 2 file transfers for 1 file).

So, the question is, what is the best way to transfer a file to storage given that we don't know what cloud platform the service is running on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this setting your proposed proxy solutions seems to be the only one and although the double transfer seems to be bad, in practice its not that evil as the cloud storage is commonly in the same datacenter as the compute nodes and therefore very fast to access.

Comment: In some cases, our files can be quite large.  Let's say, for example, the file is 2GB in size.  That can take tens of seconds, if not minutes to transfer depending on how they go between the server running the service, and the storage server. (Or am I wrong about that?)  I know that it will take quite a while to transfer the 2GB to the service, and that, by comparison, this 2nd transfer is short, but I was hoping to avoid it if possible.

Comment: Since no one else was able to come up with a better answer, I will assume that this is as good as is possible in this case.

Comment: @Jonathan with S3 (not sure about the others) you can have user upload directly to the clould. See http://doc.s3.amazonaws.com/proposals/post.html   then if you see step 3 of the diagram on that page. When the user is redirected to a URL on your service you can record the details of the file they uploaded.  Not sure if this is possible without a web browser?.  But yes 02strich should be good enough

Comment: @Jonathan: based on measurements on azure, there you can assume between 50 and 80 MBits/s between your service and the storage

Comment: Thank you!  That's helpful to know.